# Installed AWS Lighsail, Bitnami Prestashop, e-commece. Looking for my MariaDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, prestashop, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

When connecting to SSH from lighsail wed page i can see MariaDB and can access the DB @ SSH prompt.
Great!
However, when trying to find it in Database LightSail console it does not appear.
And could not connect to MySQL or Dbschema.

I am thinking it is one of these..

- installation has gone wrong in lightsail and console has not picked up that a DB is running in the instance
- I need to create a named DB in Prestashop for it to get picked up in Lightsail console and enable me to connect on my own desktop.
- Although i am registered with Lightsail and installed e-commerce for prestashop the package does not include Database, so i have to spend more money on set-up before return before i can do anything.

Attempted:

1. setting.inc.php file to get JDBC URL, blank file-SSH side in AWS.
2. Reset firewall on desktop, common port listening as inbound for ecommerce port config(3306)
3. Attempted connection with Dbschema. see below.

Error from DBschema:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Again thinking it is because it is installed, but does not know what to do? Can not find JDBC URL so using standard JDBC URL in set up, just IP & Port{SOCKET}.

Answer (score -1):

[LightSail databases](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-databases) are separate database servers managed by Amazon LightSail for you. These don't run on your LightSail instance, they run on separate servers managed by Amazon and you would configure your application to connect to these databases over a network connection. When you have an Amazon managed database server, Amazon will do things like version upgrades, monitoring and disaster recovery, and database backups for you.

Note that at this time LightSail databases only supports PostgreSQL and MySQL, not MariaDB.

What you currently have is MariaDB database software installed and running directly on your LightSail server, the same server that your Prestashop software is installed and running on. This is why when you `ssh` into the server you can see the database. Amazon is not managing your MariaDB database, Amazon is just providing the virtual machine (LightSail instance) where you have this software running. It is up to you to keep the database updated, recover it if it crashes, and make backups of it.